# How can I convert a Silverlight ImageSource to a byte[]?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, arrays, imagesource

I've got a simple ImageSource silverlight control which i have on my canvas. Works fine. Is there any way I can extract the content of an ImageSource to a byte array?

cheers!

PS. Any version of SL will be fine.

Comment: Wow. How embarrassing. I did SL stuff waaaay back :( Things we did when we were young ....

Comment: :( yeah .... where is our youth, man...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get the byte array from an ImageSource component, but you can probably create a BitmapImage and set its UriSource property, then get the byte [] from there.  Not exactly an answer to your question but hth ;)